# On ruby-1.9.3 getting OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError from net-https (Mac OSX 10.6)

Tags: ruby, openssl, osx-snow-leopard, ruby-1.9.3, net-http

I have seen a lot of people with this error and no solution seems to fix it for me:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

There seem to be a lot of solutions proposing shifting cert files around.  I've installed and uninstalled macports, homebrew, the works.  I have my keys set up right for github.  The error is occurring when trying to do a rails build that calls on a template with files up on github.

System:  Mac OSX 10.6 - recent upgrade.  Ruby 1.9.3, also a recent upgrade.  Rails 3.2.  I have googled till the cows come home and spent hours on this problem and even though there seem to be several q's like this I am holding out hope someone found a solution and hasn't yet posted it.  I think I know *why* it's happening - net/http is not finding the certs, right?  But I cannot figure out how to fix it.  Thanks in advance for any kind help.

Edit:  Further info.  Attempting the exact same build in ruby 1.9.2 (rvm use 1.9.2) completes without throwing the error.

Another edit:  I have tried all the stuff on the rvm page about the openssl package, installing that and reinstalling ruby-1.9.3 with the config flag pointing openssl at that package.  Still no joy.

One more edit:  It seems to be OpenURI that's having the problem - cannot find a way to make it aware of the cert locations :-(

Comment: Same issue here. This is absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just directly modify the http.rb source(L:669) for MacOS:

```
def use_ssl=(flag)
  flag = flag ? true : false
  if started? and @use_ssl != flag
    raise IOError, "use_ssl value changed, but session already started"
  end
  if flag && !@ca_file //added by riceball
    @ca_file = '/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt' 
  end
```

must install first

```
 port install curl-ca-bundle
```

Comment: Thanks - I've just been avoiding this but I will try that :-)

Comment: There must be a way to tell ruby where the crt files are. I mean without editing rb files in gem directories.